# How can I use a legacy class in a PCollection?

Tags: java, apache-beam

I want use Java classes from a legacy API in Beam PCollections. I am working exclusively with PCollection of Row. I cannot access the source code of the legacy API, so cannot annotate them nor declare them serializable. Its classes generally do not implement Serializable. The errors I am getting generally indicate that the legacy classes in question cannot be serialized.

I have created logical types for the legacy classes. Beam seems to accept them as Row components, and I can create and print PCollections including the legacy classes. However, when I try to transform the PCollections, I generally encounter the not serializable exception.

Among the transformations I need to use are AddFields, Group.byFieldNames.aggregateField, and Join. Right now, I'm encountering the not serializable exception when I try to AddFields with the legacy class, the first transform in the chain.

I have registered the schemas that include legacy components with the pipeline. I created custom coders for the legacy classes, using the readObject and writeObject methods of the ObjectInput/OutputStream classes and registered them with the pipeline.

Is there any general advice on how to deal with legacy classes in Beam? Examples would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you've created custom coders for the legacy classes. This is a good approach. When creating custom coders, you should make sure to handle **serialization** and **deserialization** of the legacy classes properly. You can implement custom coders by extending `Coder<T\>` and overriding the `encode` and `decode` methods.

Example custom coder for a legacy class:

```
public class LegacyClassCoder extends CustomCoder<LegacyClass> {
    @Override
    public void encode(LegacyClass value, OutputStream outStream) {
    // Serialize the LegacyClass to bytes and write them to outStream
    }

    @Override
    public LegacyClass decode(InputStream inStream) {
    // Read bytes from inStream and deserialize them to a LegacyClass instance
    }
}
```

You indicated that you've devised logical types for the legacy classes, which can be advantageous in encapsulating serialization logic and streamlining the interaction with these legacy classes.Also, beam allows the use of these logical types as elements within a Row PCollection. This approach is sound, provided that the logical types effectively manage the serialization and deserialization processes.

When using operations like `Group.byFieldNames.aggregateField` or `Join`, avoid using the legacy classes as key fields. Instead, create intermediate keys that use a serializable type.